# Querying a growing data-set

Tags: c++

We have a data set that grows while the application is processing the data set. After a long discussion we have come to the decision that we do not want blocking or asynchronous APIs at this time, and we will periodically query our data store.

We thought of two options to design an API for querying our storage:

1. A query method returns a snapshot of the data and a flag indicating weather we might have more data. When we finish iterating over the last returned snapshot, we query again to get another snapshot for the rest of the data.
2. A query method returns a "live" iterator over the data, and when this iterator advances it returns one of the following options: Data is available, No more data, Might have more data.

We are using C++ and we borrowed the .NET style enumerator API for reasons which are out of scope for this question. Here is some code to demonstrate the two options. Which option would you prefer?

```
/* ======== FIRST OPTION ============== */

// similar to the familier .NET enumerator.
class IFooEnumerator
{
    // true --> A data element may be accessed using the Current() method
    // false --> End of sequence. Calling Current() is an invalid operation.
    virtual bool MoveNext() = 0;
    virtual Foo Current() const = 0;
    virtual ~IFooEnumerator() {}
};

enum class Availability
{
    EndOfData,
    MightHaveMoreData,
};

class IDataProvider
{
    // Query params allow specifying the ID of the starting element. Here is the intended usage pattern:
    //  1. Call GetFoo() without specifying a starting point. 
    //  2. Process all elements returned by IFooEnumerator until it ends.
    //  3. Check the availability. 
    //     3.1 MightHaveMoreDataLater --> Invoke GetFoo() again after some time by specifying the last processed element as the starting point
    //                                    and repeat steps (2) and (3)   
    //     3.2 EndOfData --> The data set will not grow any more and we know that we have finished processing.
    virtual std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<IFooEnumerator>, Availability> GetFoo(query-params) = 0;
};


/* ====== SECOND OPTION ====== */

enum class Availability
{
    HasData,
    MightHaveMoreData,
    EndOfData,
};


class IGrowingFooEnumerator
{
    // HasData:
    //      We might access the current data element by invoking Current()
    // EndOfData:
    //      The data set has finished growing and no more data elements will arrive later
    // MightHaveMoreData:
    //      The data set will grow and we need to continue calling MoveNext() periodically (preferably after a short delay)
    //      until we get a "HasData" or "EndOfData" result.
    virtual Availability MoveNext() = 0;
    virtual Foo Current() const = 0;
    virtual ~IFooEnumerator() {}
};

class IDataProvider
{
    std::unique_ptr<IGrowingFooEnumerator> GetFoo(query-params) = 0;
};
```

---

**Update**

Given the current answers, I have some clarification. The debate is mainly over the interface - its expressiveness and intuitiveness in representing queries for a growing data-set that at some point in time will stop growing. The implementation of both interfaces is possible without race conditions (at-least we believe so) because of the following properties:

1. The 1st option can be implemented correctly if the pair of the iterator + the flag represent a snapshot of the system at the time of querying. Getting snapshot semantics is a non-issue, as we use database transactions.
2. The 2nd option can be implemented given a correct implementation of the 1st option. The "MoveNext()" of the 2nd option will, internally, use something like the 1st option and re-issue the query if needed.
3. The data-set can change from "Might have more data" to "End of data", but not vice versa. So if we, wrongly, return "Might have more data" because of a race condition, we just get a small performance overhead because we need to query again, and the next time we will receive "End of data".

Answer (score 0):

> "Invoke GetFoo() again after some time by specifying the last processed element as the starting point"

How are you planning to do that?  If it's using the earlier-returned `IFooEnumerator`, then functionally the two options are equivalent.  Otherwise, letting the caller destroy the "enumerator" then however-long afterwards call `GetFoo()` to continue iteration means you're losing your ability to monitor the client's ongoing interest in the query results.  It might be that right now you have no need for that, but I think it's poor design to exclude the ability to track state throughout the overall result processing.

Comment: Then you prefer the 2nd option, with the "live" iterator?

Comment: @Alex yup, that'd be the one.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on many things whether the overall system will at all work (not going into details about your actual implementation):

1. No matter how you twist it, there will be a race condition between checking for "Is there more data" and more data being added to the system. Which means that it's possibly pointless to try to capture the last few data items?
2. You probably need to limit the number of repeated runs for "is there more data", or you could end up in an endless loop of "new data came in while processing the last lot".
3. How easy it is to know if data has been updated - if all the updates are "new items" with new ID's that are sequentially higher, you can simply query "Is there data above X", where X is your last ID. But if you are, for example, counting how many items in the data has property Y set to value A, and data may be updated anywhere in the database at the time (e.g. a database of where taxis are at present, that gets updated via GPS every few seconds and has thousands of cars, it may be hard to determine which cars have had updates since last time you read the database).

As to your implementation, in option 2, I'm not sure what you mean by the `MightHaveMoreData` state - either it has, or it hasn't, right? Repeated polling for more data is a bad design in this case - given that you will never be able to say 100% certain that there hasn't been "new data" provided in the time it took from fetching the last data until it was processed and acted on (displayed, used to buy shares on the stock market, stopped the train or whatever it is that you want to do once you have processed your new data).

Comment: So even with updates, I don't see anything that falsifies my statement 1 - you will NEVER have a "guaranteed that nothing updated since you fetched the data". So then comes the question of "why bother" - why not just take the first snapshot. Does it really change that much?

Comment: In our case it is not pointless. We have a way of knowing that a data set ends and will not grow anymore. This way is not relevant to the question itself. Just trust us :)

Answer (score 0):

Read-write lock could help. Many readers have simultaneous access to data set, and only one writer.
The idea is simple:
-when you need read-only access, reader uses "read-block", which could be shared with other reads and exclusive with writers;
-when you need write access, writer uses write-lock which is exclusive for both readers and writers;